# Can i change the title bar of Sublime text is black like brackets?

Tags: macos, themes, sublimetext3

How can i change the title bar of sublime text like this image? All black finish!

[image]

Comment: They might have set the entire OS to this theme (black title bars) and not ST3 itself. Maybe.

Comment: the brackets have the black title bar, so i think ST3 can change

Comment: The settings for title bar color, etc. are contained in the compiled program itself. There is no way for the user to change it.

Comment: ok MattDMo, i got it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [@stemcc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5790986/stemcc) mentioned early it is possible now. And here's a quick solution how to do that.

1- Go to Sublime settings folder and find your theme file.

```
/Users/{userName}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/{themeName}.sublime-package
```

2- Backup your theme file just in case.

3- Add a `.zip` extension to your theme file and unarchive it.

4- You're gonna see a `{themeName}.sublime-theme` file in the unarchived files. Open it and paste these codes top of the JSON file. You can change the colors in RGB model.

```
// Windows - title bar
{
    "class": "title_bar",
    "fg": [215, 218, 224],
    "bg": [33, 37, 43]
},
```

5- Select all unarchived files (except the main folder) and compress them.

6- Change the file name from `Archive.zip` to original name `{themeName}.sublime-package`. And that's it.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

For more information about the windows element go to Sublime's documentation page.

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#elements-windows

Comment: Can you be more specific about this part? "Select all unarchived files (except the main folder) and compress them."

Comment: In the third step after we unarchive our theme file, there is gonna be a folder like {themeName}.sublime-package and the whole content inside it like assets, icons. I called this folder "main folder". And in the fifth step we're gonna archive just the content of the main folder.

Comment: For some reason when I do this the title bar is slightly darker than what i set it to. For example, i set it to R: 37 G: 41 B: 52, but when i screen shot it and check it's color codes i get R: 31 G: 35 B: 46. It loses exactly 6 for each code.. i don't understand why.

Edit: I can confirm that adding 6 to each of the RGB values fixed it, but this still makes no sense to me.

Comment: I had to reboot sublime to get this to apply

Answer (score 2):

As of [build 3127](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev), SublimeText 3 now supports custom color window title bars in macOS 10.10+.

Comment: Awesome!! Hope they release it soon

Comment: I am on 3136 via sublimetext.com/3dev - I can confirm that it works on my friend's system, but it doesn't on mine, even with same prefs/theme/color scheme. A bit confused, will post when I find solution.

Answer (score -3):

ST3 do not support custom title bar, it uses OS title bar (window of OS) so it cannot be colored by the app. OS paints this window.

Comment: if so, how Chrome affects it's window bar to show tabs on it? on osx also Visual Studio Code has its own them on the title bar so there should  be a way...